# Native cURL with CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

How can I use native cURL in server instead cURL library in codeigniter? I have cURL code which I made in native cURL in PHP, but I want it to implement with CI but CI doesn't recognize the action I want.

Comment: what i don't get, from which cURL library are you talking about ?
afaik CI doesn't have a build in cUrl Library

Comment: @PHP what is the error message that you're getting from this code within CI?

Comment: @aharen I test the code above in simple php script, it works, but when I copy it to CI i receive blank page.

Comment: @PHP that's strange, have you got `error_reporting()` enabled in CI? can you please wrap `$response = curl_exec($soap_do);` with `try {} catch () {}` and see if any Exception is thrown?

Comment: if this is working in php and not in CI then you probably have more a routing problem than a php problem

are you sure you have access to your controller - because a blank page indicates that you have turned `display_errors=off`and you are not aware of any errors

Comment: @aharen I tried to wrap $response and here's my code `if($response !== false) {
    echo '<p class="response2">'.$response.'</p>';
    $response = $response;
} ` But nothing showing, error_reporting is enable.

Comment: @sintakonte I update my code in CI, please see.

Comment: @PHP right after `\\converting` do this `try {
          $response = curl_exec($soap_do); 
          echo "<pre>";
          print_r($response);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }` instead of the `if` statement

Comment: @PHP i think @sintakonte got a valid point there. Try just printing something like `echo 'hello';` before your `curl` to test is your routing is working properly and it reaches your controller

Comment: @aharen nothings happen too.

Comment: @ PHP like @sintakonte said, you should check on your routing if you don't see any output with that

Comment: as aharen said try to type exactly after `public function search_refno_validation(){` `echo "Hello"; die();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [Guzzel](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) or [Response](http://requests.ryanmccue.info/)

Both of which have pretty extensive documentation & support

Example from Guzzel

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->get('https://api.github.com/user', ['auth' =>  ['user', 'pass']]);
echo $res->getStatusCode();
// "200"
echo $res->getHeader('content-type');
// 'application/json; charset=utf8'
echo $res->getBody();
// {"type":"User"...'
```

Comment: it req PHP 5.5.0., I'm using 5.3,. my question is how to use native not asking for alternate way.

Comment: @PHP Sorry my bad :) , could you provide some code of what you have done, expect and the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

HI try this really great library build by philsturgeon long time ago it work great

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl

read documentation carefully how this library will work

Comment: it ends the session of CI once I include the code in autoload

Comment: don't autoload, load it when u want to use it.

Comment: How can I post the `$xml_post_string()` above?